# kubernetes cannot resolve domain properly

Tags: kubernetes

After I upgraded Kubernetes to v1.7, the the domains in Nginx config and other MySQL connection fails.

this log is from Nginx:

```
nginx: [emerg] host not found in upstream "subdomain.domain.com"
```

this log is from a python app:

```
OperationalError: (_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError) (2005, "Unknown MySQL server host 'rm-xxxxxxxxxx.mysql.rds.provider.com' (110)")
```

And another connection with pymongo timed out.

All I mentioned above worked fine when I was using v1.6 or without kubernetes. I wonder if there were any differences between kubernetes v1.6 and v1.7 could result in this problem? kube-proxy should be blamed for this in my opionion, but I cannot figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

I have not enough reputation to add comment ,
can you check your kube-dns is running well?
and you can enter in the pod to set the resolv.conf of the nameserver 8.8.8.8, try it check use other dns can work